# how to replace values in data table based on another table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with 83 columns called `growthcheck`.
The vector `flag4issues` contains a subset of 21 column names of `growthcheck`. `flag4issues` is a character vector.

`test` is another vector having dimension 3 by 21. I'm debugging a code where the line

```
growthcheck[1:3, flag4issues] <- test
```

throws an error.

I tried with tranforming test to data.table, do a loop, but nothing works. Any idea?

`dput(growthcheck[1:5,flag4issues])`, `test` and `flag4issues` can be retrieved [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VceWrB5jQFCJMKj9qBFrOp9YmKmHS-2v/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table` syntax would be to specify the row index in `i` (1:3), assign the data.frame ('test') to the columns specified.  As the columns of 'growthcheck' are `numeric` class and the 'test' are `character` (`matrix`), need to convert the class before doing the assignment

```
library(data.table)
growthcheck <- growthcheck[, lapply(.SD, as.character)]
growthcheck[1:3, (flag4issues) := as.data.frame(test)]
```

-output

```
growthcheck[1:3, 1:2]
   Country
1: Austria
2: Austria
3: Belgium
                                                                                                               Obs
1:  3.A.4.3 - Population (POP, Deer): Irregularities in the time series have been been identified. Years flagged: 
2:  3.A.4.3 - Population (POP, Deer): Irregularities in the time series have been been identified. Years flagged: 
3: 3.A.4.4 - Population (POP, Goats): Irregularities in the time series have been been identified. Years flagged:
```

Comment: Many thanks ...i have still too many things to learn on data.table

Comment: I have been too optimistic...I keep getting the error: ````Error in `[.data.table`(growthcheck, 1:3, `:=`((flag4issues), as.data.frame(test))) : 
  Supplied 21 columns to be assigned 3 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.```` any further suggestion?

Comment: @efz Is it based on the same dput as I couldn't reproduce that error.  The `test` when converted to data.frame is 3 x 21 and the flag4issues is a vector of 21 elements

Comment: well, growcheck has many more columns, for the rest is the same

Comment: @efz it wouldn't matter as long as the columns in `flag4issues` matches that in the dataset

Comment: @efz as a quick test, you can check `all(flag4issues %in% names(growthcheck))`

Comment: @efz can you check whether there is any changes in structure with that of the dput structure you provided.  A `data.frame` or a `list` of columns can be directly assigned to data.table

Comment: @efz can you show the `dim(as.data.frame(test))`

Comment: > dim(as.data.frame(test))
[1] 21  3

Comment: @efz that is the issue.  In the dput, it was `dim(as.data.frame(test))#
[1]  3 21`. you need to transpose and convert to data.frame i.e. `as.data.frame(t(test))`

Comment: @efz i.e. somehow your test got transposed and now it has 21 rows and 3 columns instead of 3 rows and 21 columns

Comment: mmhh, got exactly the same problem>       growthcheck[1:3, (flag4issues) := as.data.frame(t(test))]
Error in `[.data.table`(growthcheck, 1:3, `:=`((flag4issues), as.data.frame(t(test)))) : 
  Supplied 21 columns to be assigned 3 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.

Comment: @efz can you show the `dim(as.data.frame(t(test)))` it seems a bit weird that you are still getting those errors because the `1:3` implies we are only selecting the first 3 rows, then the `j` length of columns in `flag4issues` is 21, so, if the as.data.frame(t(test))` is 3 x 21, it should work

Comment: @efz I think there is some env issues.  Can you do this on a fresh R session

Comment: this is weird dim( as.data.frame(t(test)))
[1] 1 3
> dim( as.data.frame((test)))
[1] 21  3

Comment: @efz If it is a matrix, the `t` should give the transpose.  May be you have defined `t` as something else?  Can you try on a fresh R session

Comment: thanks for your perseverance, your first solution did actually work. I missed the ```Reduce``` part of the code that tranformed ```test``` from list to matrix. thanks again